# Why does UIAlertView work in iOS 8 if it's deprecated?

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertview

I am currently running iOS 8.1.4 and I use UIAlertView in my code without any problems. But the documentation says that it is not available for iOS 8. What am I missing then?

Comment: Deprecated does not mean "not available". It means "outdated, should not be used for new projects and may be removed from future versions". Ideally, you deprecate something in version N of your framework and remove it completely in version N+3, so everyone has change to upgrade code

Comment: Post this as an answer. I'll accept.

Comment: About the only deprecated API ever actually changed to do nothing was `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier`.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you mean that mostly all that deprecated API remains usable in newer versions? It is better for me to use `UIAlertView` instead of `UIAlertViewController`  just because it is not tied to view controllers. I don't need to present it modally.

Comment: @efimovD While most deprecated APIs will still work, don't use them unless you need to support a version of iOS that doesn't have the newer API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated does not mean "not available". It means "outdated, should not be used for new projects and may be removed from future versions". Ideally, you deprecate something in version N of your framework and remove it completely in version N+3, so everyone has change to upgrade code.